# How to know if it is on or in in each case?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I have knowledge on web technologies <>
I have knowledge in web technologies

I have experience on web security <>
I have experience in web security

What is correct in each case? Why?

Comment: The answer to _Why?_ is, I'm afraid, "because that's how English is". What preposition a word takes for its arguments has to be learnt along with its meaning and its spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard "knowledge on something". You may use "knowledge in" a subject, but you usually have "knowledge **of** something". ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20knowledge%20of%2C%20have%20knowledge%20in%2C%20*%20knowledgable%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20knowledge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20knowledge%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbe%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmore%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvery%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmost%20knowledgable%20in%3B%2Cc0))

About "experience", again I have not heard "experience on something".

According to **Concise English Grammar for Foreign Students** (Longman, 1961):

- Experience **with** something (I have experience **with**
  translation)
- Experience **in** doing things (I have a lot of experience **in**
  working with children)